# Output of GAS function not the individual cell value, but the full column of values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Apps script. I created a Google Apps Script to act as a alternative for vlookup (I want static data for reasons).

I've created a function that is able to communicate between Sheet 1 "Main Sheet" (user input), and Sheet 2 "Query Sheet" (contains data results).

Intention is to compare mainSheet ColW with querySheet ColA

If mainSheet ColW matches, replace the value in mainSheet ColX with the value of querySheet ColB in the corresponding row.

Example if mainSheet Col W2 is '123' and querySheet Col A5 is '123', paste value from querySheet Col B5 into mainSheet Col X2

This is for comparing input provided by a user with data that is updated in the backend after X period of time. To reduce the need to constantly review this data, the query runs in intervals. The user sheet is populated with results.

```js
function match(){

  //Sheet with the query outputs
  var querySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID123456789"); // query results are dumped in this doc

  var querySheetTab = querySheet.getRange("query!A1:F"); //tab with the results

  //Main sheet to have query data pasted
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //current worksheet

  var mainSheetTab = mainSheet.getRange("USERSHEET!W2:X"); //Tab and range of the data. W contains a number. X is where the results of B from the querySheet go

  //values to compare
  var mainSheetVal = mainSheet.getSheetByName('USERSHEET').getRange('W2:W').getValues(); //values to match against query results

  var mainSheetComp = mainSheet.getSheetByName('USERSHEET').getRange('W2:W'); //numbers to match against query results

  var mainSheetSet = mainSheet.getSheetByName('USERSHEET').getRange('X2:X'); //Where values get pasted. 

  var getValQS = querySheet.getSheetByName('query').getRange('A1:B').getValues(); //query results includes both objects values

  var valQS = querySheet.getSheetByName('query').getRange('A1:A'); // query results

  var valSet = querySheet.getSheetByName('query').getRange('B2:B'); //desired values to paste.

  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < mainSheetVal.length; i++) {
    mainSheetSet.setValue(getValQS[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    if (mainSheetComp.getValue() == '') {
      output.push([getValQS[i][0]]);
    }
  }
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 12, output.length, 2).setValues(output);
}
```

This sheet ends up replacing X2:X with the value of A1, then A2, and continues to cycle through even with empty cells. I haven't been able to set-up a proper compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to compare the value of column "W" of `USERSHEET` sheet with the value of column "A" of `query` sheet.
- When above both values are the same, you want to put the value of column "B" of `query` sheet to the cell of column "X" of `USERSHEET` sheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- Values of `USERSHEET` were retrieved from "W:X" by one call.
- Values of `USERSHEET` were modified when the value of column "A" of `query` is the same with that of column "W" of `USERSHEET`.

  - After the values of `USERSHEET` were modified, the modified values were put to `USERSHEET`.

#### Modified script:

```
function match(){
  var querySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID123456789").getSheetByName("query");
  var queryValues = querySheet.getRange(1, 1, querySheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues(); // A:B
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("USERSHEET");
  var mainRange = mainSheet.getRange(2, 23, mainSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2); // W:X
  var mainValues = mainRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < mainValues.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < queryValues.length; j++) {
      if (mainValues[i][0] == queryValues[j][0]) {
        mainValues[i][1] = queryValues[j][1];
      }
    }
  }
  mainRange.setValues(mainValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, the column "W" and "X" of `USERSHEET` is overwritten. If you want to changed this situation, please tell me.

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @JustSomeScrub Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This compares Column W of main sheet to Column A of query sheet and puts value in column B of the query sheet into column X in main sheet in the same row as the match in column A.  It could be a little faster by moving the setValue out of the loop but I didn't want to mess around over writing your other data.  Also I have **not** tested this so there is always the possibility of needing corrections.

```
function match() {
  var qss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var qsh=qss.getSheetByName('query');
  var qrgA=qsh.getRange(2,1,qsh.getLastRow(),1);//colA
  var qrgB=qsh.getRange(2,2,qsh.getLastRow(),1);//colB
  var qvB=qrgB.getValues();
  var qvA=qrgA.getValues();
  var qvAf=qvA.map(function(r){return r[0]});//flatten array
  var mss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=mss.getSheetByName('USERSHEET');
  var mrg=msh.getRange(2,23,msh.getLastRow(),1);//colW
  var mVa=mrg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<mVa.length;i++) {
    var index=qvAf.indexOf(mvA[i][0]);
    if(index>-1) {
      msh.getRange(i + 2,24).setValue(qvB[index][0]);//put matches in same row of columnX
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll this one a try too.